# Is the Chrome API able to download files from a pre-redirect URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently trying to download a file using the Chrome API and am being given an invalid URL error.

The URL I am passing is a request to an API with a client ID which then - I presume - redirects/sends a header to download a file.

**content.js**

```
SC.resolve('https://soundcloud.com/moow-beatmaker/it-wasnt-me')
    .then(function(track) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
          'download:' + track.download_url + '?client_id=censored',
          function(response) {}
        );
    });
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.includes("download")) {
        let url = request.split(':');
        url = url[1].toString() + url[2].toString();

        chrome.downloads.download({url}, function() {
            console.log("Downloaded");
        });
    }
});
```

When debugging, the value of 'url' is the following: `https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/269174566/download?client_id=censored`

Comment: What is the source code for `SC.resolve`? Can you explain it in the post?

Comment: You're missing `':'` when reassembling the URL. Also don't mangle the URL, simply send an object like {action: 'download', url: '.....'}

Comment: @Black-Hole SC.resolve is apart of the SoundCloud API. It retrieves information on any given song.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm not sure what you mean. When reassembling the URL is exactly as it is as I wrote on the post, there is no missing ':'.

Comment: @wOxxOm Never mind, sending the URL using an object seemed to fix my error, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Use devtools debugger with a breakpoint inside the listener and you'll see the missing ':' :-)